# How can I make Windows XP mouse move like it does in OSX?

Tags: macos, windows-xp

After using OSX nearly exclusively for the past few years, I now need to do a lot of work on a Windows XP box. I've seen lots of stuff on the internet about making the OSX mouse move like the windows mouse, but not the other way around.

So how can I get the mouse under windows XP to move like it does under OSX? I was running OSX 10.6 if that makes a difference.

**Update:** It's hard to describe exactly how it is different. Under windows it seems more jerky, not as smooth. It seems harder to make fine adjustments to the position of the mouse in drawing and CAD programs. Small movements of the mouse make large movements of the cursor. I've read things about acceleration curves, perhaps that's where the difference lies. I've different "Pointer Speeds" and "Enhance pointer precision" in the mouse properties control panel, and while they help, it's still not the same thing. I'm sure there's nothing wrong with my computer (and it's the same microsoft mouse I was using under OSX, so I don't think it's a problem with the mouse), it's just that I'm now very used to the way it works under OSX.

Really, I just want some utility that makes the mouse work exactly like in OSX, with all the same options available.

Comment: What is difference that you are after?

Comment: We need to know the feature you are looking for? The OSX mouse and Windows mouse difference is not well known for many users expect me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called **Slowmousion** that can change the speed of the cursor when you hold down a certain key. Unfortunately, the author's website is down, but since Slowmousion is GPL licensed, here's a mirror of an old version:

http://www.filedropper.com/slowmousionv11

---

It's funny you ask this, because I always wanted a way to make the OSX cursor behave like a Windows cursor. If you ever decide you've had enough of the acceleration curve on OSX, you can disable OSX's mouse acceleration by following the instructions here:

http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/02/kill-os-x-mouse-acceleration-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Yeah, I see lots of things on the internet about making the OSX mouse work like windows, but practically nothing about the other way!